# How do I correctly use `always` blocks?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

The following is a snippet from a code I wrote in verilog for XST. The log is full of errors. How do I correct the code? How and where do I use `always@()` and `@()` blocks? Where do I use blocking and non blocking assignments?

```
input wire CLOCK;
input wire [31:0] OUT_SQRT;
output wire [31:0] IN_SQRT;
input wire [31:0] RANDP;

integer randp;
integer flagp;
integer sqrootp;
integer check_primep;

always @(posedge CLOCK and flagp != 0)
begin
    #10
    @(posedge and flagp != 0 )
    begin
        flagp = sqrootp%check_primep;

        if(flagp != 0 and check_primep < sqrootp)
        begin
            check_primep = check_primep + 1;
        end

        @(posedge and flagp == 0)
        begin
            flagp = 1;
            check_primep = 2;
            randp = RANDP;
            #5
            IN_SQRT = randp;
            #10
            sqrootp = OUT_SQRT;
        end
end
```

Comment: You need to add some signal name for posedge. `@(posedge OF_WHAT and flagp != 0 )`. Use non-blocking while coding sequential blocks and blocking assignments for combinational blocks. Of course the code is not synthesizable due to manual delays and many other things.

Comment: Could you explain to me the things I need to do to make it synthesizable? Aren't all statements in an always block executed in parallel? What if I want the statements in the above always block to be executed sequentially?

Comment: All `always` blocks in a module are executed concurrently. But not all the statements in a single always block. Read some material about verilog maybe some book or online reading will help a lot.

Comment: Suggested daily reading : https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf

Comment: You are asking many questions in one post. Perhaps best for you would be to complete a tutorial on Verilog. There is a free one available at http://vol.verilog.com/ Mac

Answer (score 1):

A flip-flop is implied using:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  flip_flop_q <= flip_flop_d;
end
```

To make some thing synchronously (sampled on the clock) enabled:

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (flagp != 0) begin
    flip_flop_q <= flip_flop_d;
  end
end
```

Combinatorial logic is implied using:

```
always @* begin
  comb_logic = a + b;
end
```

Things like the following (delays) are not synthesizable:

```
#10
@(posedge and flagp != 0 ) // no always just a delay waiting for criteria
```

Often used in test harnesses to wait for signals like resets etc being released.

```
initial begin
  @(posedge reset_n);
  @(posedge clk);
  @(posedge clk);
  //begin test procedure
end
```

If you need to wait for a signal in synthesisable verilog you need to build a FSM (Finite State Machine) to sequence your logic.